# How to remove most index.ts files from my project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs

I'm looking to optimize my React folder structure. 
It looks like this:

```
- components
  - Header
    - Header.tsx
    - Header.styles.ts
    - index.ts
```

The `index.ts` is just there to allow me to import the `Header` component with `import { Header} from "components/Header`. This works because I'm using `babel-plugin-module-resolver`. Now, since my folder name is always the same as the main file name inside my `components` folder, I would like to be able to import the header with `import { Header } from "components"` and have a Babel plugin resolve this to `import { Header } from "components/Header/Header"`.  ***This would mean I could remove the index.ts***

**Which Babel plugin can do this?**

I'm already using `babel-plugin-module-resolver` to resolve the `components` folder. My problem is that i'm also using TypeScript so how do I tell the TypeScript compiler that this module is being resolved like this?

Please help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just have your index.ts in your components take care of that normally. I don't think that this has anything to do with `babel-plugin-module-resolver`, it's just how index.ts/js files work in general. https://alligator.io/react/index-js-public-interfaces/

You should be able to get what you are looking for by doing the following in your index.ts file in your component directory:

You import your Header component and then directly export it.

```
import {Header} from './Header/Header'
export Header
```

Or you might be able to do a symmetrical export depending on your setup:

```
export {Header} from './Header/Header'
```